# Magento - How to change the font throughout the site using typekit?

Tags: html, css, magento, fonts

I would like to use a different font that is not from the usual font-family.

To include this font in my site, I have a two-line JavaScript code from typekit.com which needs to be put into the pages of my website where this font needs to be applied.

But since I would like to apply this font thru out my website, where should I put this JavaScript code so that the font gets applied thru throughout the site.

I am using Magento 1.6.2.0 version and have created my own theme which sits in `app/design/frontend/default/mytheme` and `skin/frontend/default/mytheme`

If some one could tell me where to put the following JavaScript code,

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://use.typekit.com/ysw8aaa.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

I would be really grateful to them.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

According to the [knowledge-base](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-to-add-custom-javascript) and [these](http://design-tips.com/web-design/magento/109/add-js-to-all-pages/) [blogs](http://www.anunaydahal.com/magento/include-a-javascript-file-into-magento-templates/)

```
<default>
    <action method="addJs"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://use.typekit.com/ysw8aaa.js"></script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script></action>
</default>
```

or, more reliably, combine them into a single custom script file and use:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>yourdir/yourscriptname.js</script></action>
```

Comment: Sorry to sound really dumb but I dont know how to combine the above code into a single .js file. Also after creating a single .js file which file should I put the `<default></default>` line into?

Comment: Well, since it looks like you don't own the first script, you're probably better off just using two lines. Try. Read the last link in my answer. It's short and describes exactly where to make the change.

Comment: URLs are broken - can we include this information in the answer, as other sites are unreliable

Answer (score -1):

Go to /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.html (or whichever template path u are using)

Right above:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
```

Add:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://use.typekit.com/ysw8aaa.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

Something to keep in mind this is a external link so it slows down your site.

Comment: I tried you method, but nothing really changed. Should I remove the `Verdana Geneva sans-serif` font that is their at various places in my `styles.css` o will that get overridden automatically with the inclusion of new script?